# ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission .NET Standar 2.0

Tags: c#, xamarin, gps

Estou quebrando a cabeça e buscando um exemplo de código que faça a solicitação de permissão a algum recuro (câmera, GPS), e todos que encontro fazem uso da ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission, porém o pacote Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat é incompatível com .NET Standard 2.0.

Alguém tem alguma dica sobre como solicitar permissões em runtime neste caso?

Mesmo o artigo do link a seguir, me parece utilizar este pacote.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui compreender o processo.

Bastou construir o código na MainActivity.cs e as coisas funcionaram.

Segue um link interessante para quem estiver tentando compreender esta questão das permissões a acesso em runtime.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uzpy3qdYXmE

Está em inglês, mas dentro do contexto é bem fácil de companhar.